# Eclipse Debugging Trouble

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to check a variable state debugging with Eclipse a small J2EE application but I'm getting into trouble with the debugger which runs a class with the same name as the one I'm debugging from another project.

I really don't understand what's happening there ! I'm adding a breakpoint at the beginning of the line I want to in my class but when Eclipse asks me to change of perspective, another class is running.

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: There's more than you need in the classpath. Set Build Classpath -> 'Order and Export' for your project. You should probably have to clean up unnecessary entries on Projects and Source tabs.

Comment: I checked my "Build Path" on my project but all seems to be normal !

Comment: Since this is a JEE application, I'm assuming you're running this in an Java application server and debugging through Eclipse. Typically an application server will have multiple class loaders, so you might need to play around with your class loader settings in your server.xml

Comment: It's likely *running* the class you intend, it's just *opening* a different source file to show you as you step through instructions with the running JVM. The simplest solutions are to either use unique fully qualified type names in your projects, get down to a single copy if they're copies of the same class, or Close the projects containing the type you don't care about so it's not considered when trying to find the relevant source file.